# In my iPod whose os is ios 9.3.1，once click textfield, status bar hidden. no matter what, status bar cann`t display

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my iPod whose os is ios 9.3.1，once click textfield, status bar hidden.  no matter what,  status bar cann`t display. but it does not happen in ios 10.3.1

I tryed

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return NO;
}
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to set, **View controller-based status bar appearance** in `.plist` file must be `YES`.